# usb dongle key. trick the computer or clone the usb stick

Tags: certificate-authority

I have a machine (CNC) which mills in plastic. Each plastic cube comes with a USB stick. On the stick it is a virtual plastic cube.
   I have to connect the usb stick to the computer. 
   When i send my work from the computer to the milling machine, the computer memorizes the place where the piece was placed and record data on the stick, so stick can be thrown away after each empty spaces was occupied
qustion: can i macke a clone of the new stick / or trick the computer that always has an empty stick connected? Thank you[image]

Comment: Possibly.  It depends a lot about the software part.  You will need to search how the USB stick talks to the software on the computer.  On linux this can be performed with `usbmon` (a kernel module) and Wireshark, no clue about other OSes.